# How to wrap LI tag text for mobile version without js/jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I am setting up breadcrumb for my web site. which has following UI.
[image]

Here "My Account" is in seperate "li" tag. "/ View My Order History / Order# 0005073140" is in seperate "li" tag. 
I need to have following format
[image]

If I remove "/ Order# 0005073140" text then "My Account / View My Order History"  comes to one line. Since this issue is for mobile version I need to set this wrapping only for Mobile version.

If I remove the width for DIV tag the whole text is set to one line like in below. [image]

It doesn't look good as it is touching the edges of mobile(used chrome dev tool  to take pictures).

Since this is for Responsive design , I need to have this only for Mobile version. 
I appreciate your help indeed.

Original Code is here

```css
.breadcrumb {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                
                <li>
                    <a href="/MyAccount/Index">My Account</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="active">
                            <a href="/MyAccount/OrderHistory">View My Order History</a>  / Order# 0005073140

                </li>

            </ol>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your desired output.  It is not clear to me.

You could place the text in its own `<li>`, like so:

```
....

<li class="active">
  <a href="/MyAccount/OrderHistory">View My Order History</a>
</li>

<li>Order# 0005073140</li>
```

And then add the following CSS rules to handle them, like below:

```
.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb li:after {
    content: '/';
}
```

**See running demo:**

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb li:after {
    content: '/';
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">

    <li>
      <a href="/MyAccount/Index">My Account</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active">
      <a href="/MyAccount/OrderHistory">View My Order History</a>
    </li>

    <li>Order# 0005073140</li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding Order # in separate li tag solves this issue. Thanks Ochi.

Comment: Glad I could help :)